# Selenium WebDriver C# not find element by FindElement(by.xpath)

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find the element `<td>!!mmm region test !!mmm region test</td>` in the table below.

```
...
<div class="panel-body cim-padding-zero">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <section id="UserListArea">
            <div class="jtable-main-container">
               ...
<table class="jtable">
    ...
    <tbody>
        <tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even Pointer" data-record-key="88">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="jtable-data-row Pointer" data-record-key="301">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even Pointer" data-record-key="302">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="jtable-data-row Pointer" data-record-key="524">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even Pointer jtable-row-selected" data-record-key="651">
            <td>!!mmm region test !!mmm region test</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>        
...
```

I have tried this

```
IWebElement UserList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//section[@id='UserListArea']/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td"));
```

and this

```
IWebElement UserList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='UserListArea']/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td"));
```

but in every case I get the error

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//section[@id='UserListArea']/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td"}

Comment: Could you please format your HTML better? Don't put everything in 1 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, next time edit your HTML more properly. It is very uncomfortable to read

```
//tr[@data-record-key="651"]/td
```

That works for me

Comment: Dmitry, keep calm. I can't give link because webpage have restricted information. If you want I can send .htm or .html file but in this file we can't explore element. To illustrate webpage I can share screen: http://prntscr.com/8p2ibw (red frame is example of record which I can't find in WebDriver).

Comment: The think is that the XML is definitely correct. Maybe webrdiver tries to find this element when it is not ready yet ? Try using a            Thread.sleep(1500); (1500 in Miliseconds) before accessing this element, maybe it will work

Comment: Dmitry, after a day of fight with this I have success. Enough using Thread.sleep. In website I don't see that the element are still loading, but they really must be. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: No problems, glad that i helped.

Comment: Please don't use `Thread.sleep()`. it's a much better practice to use `WebDriverWait` and wait until a specific element exists. It's a less fragile way of waiting.

Comment: In which library there is method WebDriverWait? I don't have this method. I use using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below Xpath:-

```
//*[@id='UserListArea']/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[contains(.,'!!mmm region test !!mmm region test')]
```

OR

```
//*[@id='UserListArea']//tr[@data-record-key='651']/td
```

OR

```
//tr[@class='jtable-data-row jtable-row-even Pointer jtable-row-selected']/td
```

If still selenium show you `NoSuchElementException` then check that if there is any frame present. if frame is there then you need to switch to frame first

Comment: Sorry, any of them doesn't work. In my webpage aren't frame phase. DO you have any other idea? Do you need more html of my page?

Comment: yes it will help. if you can share the link then it will be more good

Comment: I edit html code in my first post and I give more html code, but of course I must delete some restricted informations.

Comment: I have added one more xpath. hope it will help you

Comment: Still doesn't work. Besides 3 xpath is not clear because this xpath doesn't indicate tr[5] but whole tr.